# Count of Maximum code chef.Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++

Hi I started doing code chef beginner problems and got stuck at this one.I tried reducing the stack memory by declaring the arrays globally but that doesn't work too.Here is my code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define max 101

int main()
{        
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        int a[max];
        int c[max]={0};

        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            c[a[j]]++;
        }
        int temp=0;
        int x=0;
        for(int k=0;k<n;k++)
        {
            if(c[k]>temp)
            {
                temp=c[k];
                x=k;                    
            }
        }
        cout<<x<<" "<<temp<<endl;            
    }        
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `0 <= a[j] < 101` since it is used as `c`'s array index?

Comment: i tried changing max to even 10001 but i still get the error,it works on my computer though .

Comment: Are input values guaranteed to be bounded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need a data structure that does not limit the input value to be bounded, or just change your algorithm.

Either use `std::map<int, int>` in place of `c` to count occurence of each number, or just sort `a` to aggregate same values and count.